# Disable Jquery Mobile Ajax Navigation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

Despite endless reading of the API documentation and internet post I cannot get the AJAX Navigation to be disabled.

**CURRENT SCRIPTS**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind(“mobileinit”, function() { 
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; 
});
</script>
```

**MY ISSUE**

Using ASP.NET Forms When I login from a root page (index.aspx)
I should be redirected to a folder (LOGIN) where the rest of my site is but the folder is not passed to URL.

I GET **/Page.aspx**

Instead of **/LOGIN/Page.aspx**

**QUESTION**

How to fix the navigation behavior for ASP.NET forms Login Submit **OR**

How to disable AJAX Navigation globally for Jquery Mobile 1.4

Comment: If you do exactly what you are doing in the code above, but do it before calling the jquery mobile script it works correctly and disables ajax navigation completely.  I'm using this myself.  Found the example and explanation here: http://amitkumarsharma.com/jquery-mobile-and-disabling-ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution as below:

just add to your master form:

**data-ajax="false"**

```
<form runat="server" data-ajax="false">
```

This will disable ajax navigation on the selected form.

As this is ASP.NET adding it to the sites master form will disable AJAX form submit behavior site wide.

This way you do not need to use the script as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is older, but having just dealt with this. If you want to disable Ajax Navigation globally add the following script **AFTER**  Jquery, but **BEFORE** Jquery mobile. Order is very important here.

The code would look something like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
  $.extend($.mobile, {
    ajaxEnabled: false
  });
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.js"></script>
```

see http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a3/#docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution Sam